# mprof for memory_profiler is not running

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, python-3.5, memory-profiling

I install memory_profiler via pip using pip install -U memory_profiler  and try working with mprof using:
mprof run 
mprof plot

But get the following error:

> ERROR-mprof is not recognised as an internal or external command.

any work around?

Python 3.5 version being used.

NOTE: This is not a duplicate. There have been questions like this prior but no answer yet!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run it. Are you using the same virtual environment from where you ran pip install memory_profiler?

mprof run outputs a .dat file which is read by mprof plot. So, essentially, these are 2 separate commands.

mprof plot does not easily work with Mac OS as we need python framework version. More details from [here](https://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html).

Answer (score 1):

Hey I too was facing some issue running `mprof`.

I was using `pipenv`. Therefore I could run mprof by running the command:

```
pipenv run mprof run python python_script.py
```